# How can I submit post on facebook comment using graph API version 2.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We are working on website which will let its user:-

- To add a comment on Facebook comments.
- For this we require to list posts of timeline/home-line feeds.
- We did lot of study on graph API and found that our app must be approved for read_stream and publish_action permission.
- We would be able t fetch posts of logged in facebook user from facebook server once we would have been approved for **read_stream** and similarly we require **publish_action** to add a comment on post.
- We have made many requests to facebook for **read_stream** extended permission but everytime facebook has rejected our request.
- This URL: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2 indicates that this extended permission is not allowed for ios/Android and web based applications.
- Does any stack-genius knows how hootsuite.com is able to fetch feeds from facebook for logged in user and able to add a comment on facebook posts. for reference please find https://hootsuite.com.
- When we have started with this project then that time graph API was supporting read_stream and posts were coming and we were also able to add comments on posts. But after 15 days of trial period, the functionality of read_stream has stopped and facebook has never approved our app.

Please suggest how we can get our to be approved for **read_stream** and **publish_action**.

Please suggest if **facebook has any partnership plan for providing such extended permission**. Because if hootsuite.com is able to fetch data from facebook then we can also fetch same data from facebook using same API.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds a lot like a Facebook customer support question. There is no specific programming question here... Rather what you are asking is for advice on *dealing* with Facebook not approving your application for certain permissions...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be an attempt to reach Facebook customer support.

Comment: You will not get `read_stream`. All you can get is `user_posts` to read their own posts (plus whatever friends that are also using the app might have given it read access to on their own.)

Answer (score 0):

Like you already mention, the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4) is clear on this topic:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client
>   on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example,
>   Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In
>   addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this
>   permission.

Furthermore; some apps have indeed a special partnership with Facebook, for example HootSuite. It is currently not possible to apply for such partnerships; Facebook will reach out to you if you could be an interesting partner.